# Moment.js formatting

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to format time in the format `'10h:23 am'`. The code i am using is this

```
moment('15/10/2015 14:20', 'DD/MM/YYYY H:mm').format('DD-MM-YYYY hh:m a');
```

It give the output `15-10-2015 02:20 pm`. How can I get the output `15-10-2015 02h:20 pm`
I am using moment.js version : 2.8.4 in my application.

Answer (score 3):

You can escape *literals* in the expression with the `[]` notation:

```
moment('15/10/2015 14:20', 'DD/MM/YYYY H:mm').format('DD-MM-YYYY hh[h]:m a');
```

Reference: [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), take a look at the *Escaping characters* subsection.